# How to import MySQL using Gradle and connect into JavaFX

Tags: mysql, gradle, javafx

I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and `JavaFX 10` for my practice learning. I want to connect [MySQL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6) and import it using `Gradle`.

I found multiple example in internet but I din't found any latest, most of the function is already depreciated and reading so much different example makes me confused.

Comment: [Gradle Docs - Introduction to Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html) <-- Goes over how to manage dependencies using Gradle. [Maven Central - MySQL Connector/J](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11) <-- Link to the MySQL JDBC driver library in the Maven Central repository. If you click on the latest version it'll take you to another page where you can see a tabbed area that's currently set on "Maven". Click on "Gradle" to see how to declare the dependency in Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read first the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) instead of reading multiple example.

I assume that you are beginner.

> 1.) First thing to do is to Download the [MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) to intall the Server into your machine. Remember that things won't work without this.
>
> During the installation you will need to set your `Server PORT`, `root password` or `add a new user`, just remember the `Server PORT` and `root Password` and leave things in default.
>
> 2.) Go to [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/). We need to import the [MySQL Connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11). In order to import the [MySQL Connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11) into Gradle we need to get the correct group, name and version for it.
>
> You notice that in Maven Central there are multiple selection on how you can import the jar into your project, this time we want to import it using Gradle, 
>   so you have to choose the Gradle and copy the code: `compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'`
>
> **NOTE** - In order to avoid problems, just always choose and use the latest version of [MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and [MySQL Connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11), at the moment the latest version is `8.0.11`.
>
> 3.) In [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), in order to import in Gradle, in your project there is `build.gradle` click it to open then paste the code you copied in `dependencies`.
>
> it should look like:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
}
```

> 4.) Create a class where you want to connect into MySQL, the below code is my example. 
>   `Main.Class`

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Connection conn = null;
        String user = "whatEverUserNameYouSetup";
        String password = "whatEverPasswordYouSetup";
        String database = "whatEverTheNameOfYourDatabase";
        int port = 3306; //default port, change it depending on your setup
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getConstructor().newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + port + "/" + database, user, password);

            // Do something with the Connection

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The documentation is your friend.

**UPDATE:** If you run on error something like

```
Wed Dec 09 22:46:52 CET 2015 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

then you need to set `useSSL` to `false`, the code will be look like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties(); //I use Properties to make things easer. 
        properties.setProperty("user", "root");
        properties.setProperty("password", "YourPassword");
        properties.setProperty("useSSL", "false"); //Set useSSL to false to solve the problem.

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getConstructor().newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", properties);

            // Do something with the Connection

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```